# How to navigate to another page without calling the page's constructor

Tags: silverlight

My first post here so hope somebody can help. I am pretty new to C# and Silverlight so please be gentle.

Here is my current issue/problem.

I have MainPage.xaml which has a Grid control to show pages. When my site loads up I would like to show a UserControl page for either logging in or registering.

I have created a UserControl page, lets call it ctrlLogon.xaml. ctrlLogon hosts a frame that will hold either the logon or register page. I am using the frame because I am using a custom transition between the logon and register page.

The logging in happens on the LoginPage.xaml which uses a wcf services to communicate with the database. That is fine, but I need an event handler to notify ctrlLogon if the user logs in successfully or fails to logon.

In ctrlLogon.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ctrlLogon : UserControl
{
    pgLogonPage newLogonPage;

    public ctrlLogon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newLogonPage = new pgLogonPage();
        newLogonPage.LoggedInOK += new EventHandler(newLogonPage_LoggedInOK);
        newLogonPage.LoginFailed += new EventHandler(newLogonPage_LoginFailed);
    }

    void newLogonPage_LoggedInOK(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void newLogonPage_LoginFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Then either through a button click or whichever means I use:

ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/pgLogonPage.xaml"), UriKind.Relative);

This works fine by navigating to pgLogonPage.

My problem comes in that the I create and instance of pgLogonPage in order to set up the event handler, but Navigate also creates an instance of pgLogonPage, so the following does not work:

```
public partial class pgLogonPage : Page
{
    ServiceClient smsClient;

    public pgLogonPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Client = new ServiceClient();
        Client.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs (Client_LoginCompleted);
    }

public event EventHandler LoggedInOK;

    public void OnLoggedInOK()
    {
        if (LoggedInOK != null)
            LoggedInOK(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public event EventHandler LoginFailed;
    public void OnLoginFailed()
    {
        if (LoginFailed != null)
            LoginFailed(this, new EventArgs());
    }


    void Client_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Contains("Success"))
        {
            OnLoggedInOK();                            
        }

        else
        {
            OnLoginFailed();
        }
    }
```

}

LoggedInOK and LoginFailed event handlers are always null. I am thinking it is because the two instances of pgLogonPage are being created. I could be wrong so please any help to get this working is appreciated. If there is something not clear please let me know.

Kind regards

Neill

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to StackOverflow.

The navigation framework will cause an instantiation of the target page so the page's constructor will be called whether you like it or not (the page object needs to be constructed at some point - right?).

Usually a default parameterless constructor is used - so the question is - how to notify the target control that a certain condition has occured? Simple, you can add public property like

```
public bool MyCondition {get; set;}
```

to the target control, and set it after an event in the navigation framework occurs and the target control/page is constructed.

Hope that helps a bit,
Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Maciek, Will look into what you have mentioned.

Comment: P.S. Can you think then perhaps of another way to call the newLogonPage.LoggedInOK += new EventHandler(newLogonPage_LoggedInOK);
        newLogonPage.LoginFailed += new EventHandler(newLogonPage_LoginFailed);
tx

Comment: Well... I'd go for WCF Ria based authentication... check out Silverlight Business Application template. Also, check out WCF Ria code gallery and samples for Authorization samples.

Comment: Hi all, Tx for the info although the Business Application template didn't really have what i needed as it doesn't make use of custom navigations. Anyhow I did manage to find a way round my problem, albeit not the most elegant of solutions. So for anybody that is interested here is how i did it. On my LogonPage once the user logs on successfully i apply the following code to gain access back to my main page. MainPage rootPage = Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage; In my MainPage i call ctrlLogon's OnLoggedIn event handler, as this allowed me to work my way back.